# How to invoke controller function with directive expression `&` binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### Function callback after end of animation is undefined - angularjs

I am trying to make a callback as soon as the animation ends.
Here's the [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGdMYp) that I tried. Please open the chrome debugger to see the console log messages. The callback is coming back as undefined.

Could you please help me understand why the callback is not picking up?

Here's the code snippet. More details are available in the link above:

```
 angular.module('animApp', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    
  $scope.loadUrl = function(event) {
    console.log("i am here");
  }
})

.directive('animationend', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            animationend: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var callback = scope.animationend(),
                  events = 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd' +
                        'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd';
       console.log("scope", scope);
            element.on(events, function(event) {
        console.log("elem", element[0]);
        console.log("event", event);
        console.log('callback', callback);
                callback.call(element[0], event);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<svg class="progress-circle definite" width="100" height="100" 
     animationend="loadUrl">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the function in the HTML:

```
<svg class="progress-circle definite" width="100" height="100" 
     ̶a̶n̶i̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶e̶n̶d̶=̶"̶l̶o̶a̶d̶U̶r̶l̶"̶  animationend="loadUrl($event)">
</svg>
```

Invoke the callback with a locals object:

```
app.directive('animationend', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            animationend: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶b̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶=̶ ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶a̶n̶i̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶e̶n̶d̶(̶)̶,̶
            var events = 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd' +
                         'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd';
            element.on(events, function(event) {
                var callback = scope.animationend;
                ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶b̶a̶c̶k̶.̶c̶a̶l̶l̶(̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶[̶0̶]̶,̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶)̶;̶
                callback({$event: event});
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

From the Docs:

> - `&` or `&attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and the isolate scope definition `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }`, the isolate scope property localFn will point to a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope. This can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as `localFn({amount: 22}`).
>
> [—AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to make it more meaningful. Thanks for the awesome answer!